# Backspace causes entire line to clear after user input

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface

When I output to the console and then wait for user input using readline(), as per so:

```
<?php

fwrite(STDOUT, 'Would you like some apple pie? [y/N]');
readline();
```

And the user first enters some response (for example, they mistype and they enter 'T'), without pressing enter yet, if the user then wants to correct that response by pressing backspace until the whole response is gone, the entire line is cleared. This is kind of jarring, and it doesn't seem necessary (because other commands seem to be just fine with the user clearing any input before pressing enter).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readline function accept an argument which allow you to ask the user and avoid the line clear.

```
<?php

$answer = readline('Would you like some apple pie? [y/N]');
```

You can refer to the documentation of [readline](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I never even considered that, makes a lot of sense!